# Good Practice to extend models?

Tags: java, android, performance, model, extend

I'm using the following model in a listview:

```
public class ListItem {
    private int _Id;
    private String Name;


    public ListItem() {
        this._Id = 0;
        this.Name = "";
    }

    public ListItem(int Id, String Name) {
        this._Id = Id;
        this.Name = Name;
    }
        public int getId() {
        return this._Id;
    }

    public void setId(int c) {
        this._Id = c;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.Name;
    }

    public void setName(String c) {
        this.Name = c;
    }
}
```

I have some extra data that will be displaying once they click on the item they want to view. Since I'm pulling this info from a database and I'm not limiting the number of items they put in the database, I was wondering if I could extend my model in another model. Something like (you can correct me if this is the wrong way to write an extend model, if extending models is not a big deal):

```
public class ItemDetails extends ListItem {
    private String itemType, Manufacturer, Qty, Notes;
    public ItemDetails () {
        this._Id = 0;
        this.Name = "";
        this.itemType = "";
        this.Manufacturer = "";
        this.Qty = "";
        this.Notes = "";
    }
    public Ammo(int _Id, String name, String itemType,
            String manufacturer, String qty, String notes) {
        this._Id = _Id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.itemType = itemType;
        this.Manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.Qty = qty;
        this.Notes = notes;
    }

    // Get Variables //
    public int get_Id() {
        return this._Id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.Name;
    }

    public String getItemType() {
        return itemType;
    }

    public String getManufacturer() {
        return Manufacturer;
    }

    public String getQty() {
        return Qty;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return Notes;
    }

    // Set Variables //
    public void set_Id(int c) {
        this._Id(c);
    }

    public void setName(int c) {
        this.Name = c;
    }

    public void setItemType(String c) {
        itemType = c;
    }

    public void setManufacturer(String c) {
        Manufacturer = c;
    }

    public void setQty(String c) {
        Qty = c;
    }

    public void setNotes(String c) {
        Notes = c;
    }

}
```

Would this be a bad idea? Would I be better off just having to different models or one model and only returning the data I need from the List then getting the rest of the data later? I'm trying to write clean code with this, and have as little duplicate code as possible. I am also wanting my code to be efficient and perform well , but I'm not sure if this might be a good idea.

Comment: Did your code compile . i asm seeing multiple issue . Why is the ListItem class constructor SpinnerItem()? same in ItemDetails class Ammo ? also Why do you need this ListItems li; ? you can directly access this.set_Id(0)

Comment: You got me on the first two questions. I'll admit, I threw these together for the question, I have yet to actually implementing this in my code. They should be updated now. On the third question, I only uses notepad, so I guess I should have took more time to write this out. The question is about using something like this in practice. The code is just there so that you understand where I'm going with this... My bad.

Comment: one correction . you can directly access this._Id = 0 from ItemDetails, by declaring _id as protected.

Comment: Ok, so I missed the protected part, but fixed the rest. If I declare it protected, I should be good, and you think this would work?

Comment: also remove the get/set method of _Id and Name in ItemDetails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not using most of the code (variables and methods) from the class you are extending from. If you don't explicitly need to get an object of ListItem when you create an object of ItemDetails (like `ListItem item = new ItemDetails();`) you have actually no reason to extend that class. In that case your code is definitely cleaner, if you make it not to extend.

Comment: So, If I have lets say, 10 items in my db table, if I only want to display 3 or 4 of them on in the listview, but want to display all of them on a details activity/fragment, this would be a good idea, but otherwise, its not? The idea is to use all variables from the table I am extending, in most cases.

Comment: I meant it generally. Now you have changed your code and it makes more sense. If you remove the overriding methods from ItemDetails which do the same as the methods from the extending class (like getName()), it would make sense to use extend here.

Comment: Just to round this up. You usually extend class a from class b, if a is a specialization of b (b is a generalization of a). It has to do with oop. For example if you have a class 'human' and a class 'student' it would semantically make sense to make student extend human.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write clean code you should understand that the constructor calls the ListItem constructor and already initializes fields "_Id" and "Name" and overriding methods with no need to change them is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but like I said before the code itself is just there to help people understand my question.